# Trigger a click on a span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to click a span using jQuery. (I'm using rails and foundation)

```
<div class = "row my-row" id="current-my-row">
 <div class = "large-12 my-row-heading" id="my-row-click">
  <%= image_tag "some_img.png"%>
  <span class="title">This is the title</span>
  <span class="details"><%= image_tag "other_img.png"%>DETAILS</span>
 </div>
  <div class = "large-12 my-row-details">
    all details
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery function:

```
$('.details').on("click", function() {
  .... whatever I want it to do...
  //my-row-details slides down. 
}
```

On clicking "DETAILS", whatever I want it to do happens.

But, as part of another jQuery function I want to trigger a click on it.

I tried :

```
$('.details').click();
$('.details').trigger("click");
$('#my-row-click .details').click();
$('#my-row-click').trigger("click");
$('.details').trigger("click");
$('#my-row-click > span:nth-child(3)').click();
$('#my-row-click > span:nth-child(3)').trigger("click");
```

But I can't seem to trigger a click. i.e. my-row-details does not slide down.

Any help?

UPDATE:
commented all the other code: (assume this is all the function on click does)

```
$('.details').on("click", function() {
  $('.my-row-details').slideDown();
}
```

Instead of triggering a click, I tried replacing it with this line:

```
 `$('.my-row-details').slideDown();`
```

This won't work either. But it works if I actually go click "DETAILS"

Comment: `$('.details').trigger("click");` should work.  There's something else going on, try posting the code.

Comment: even thios `$('.details').click();` should work can you check for errors?

Comment: try `alert($('.details').length);` just before firing `$('.details').click();` and see what count you get.

Comment: rather than triggering a click event on the .detail - which then calls a function to slide something down - why don't you simply call the function that the click invokes?

Comment: @vijayP I get length 1

Comment: do you have multiple `row` div? please `alert($('.my-row-details').length);` too.

Answer (score 3):

Both `.click()` and `.trigger("click");` should actually work.

However, triggering an event, defined in your own code, sounds like a bad idea.
There is a better way to do this:

```
function openDetails() {
    // Whatever you want to do
}

$('.details').on("click", openDetails);
```

"as part of another jquery function":

```
openDetails();
```

That way, you can be sure that this behavior is achieved, in a clear and readable way.

Comment: this is what I was suggesting - trigger the same function rather than a click event. Well done Yeldar

Comment: did this. Still only works if I manually click. But not as a part of another jquery function.

Comment: @sakshik12 Perhaps, you rely on `this` context in your handler. Show the whole handler code ("....whatever I want it to do..."). Also, check if you have any errors in a console - if you do, post the error message here.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev please check the update. There is no use of `this`.

Comment: @sakshik12 Do you have an element with ID `my-row-details`? In your code, it looks like you only have elements with **class** `my-row-details`. So, probably, that's a problem.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that was a mistype here, since I had to change the names before posting online. Using `.my-row-details` only. Thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

The function that was calling the click() was to be executed on page load. Not on an event. And I had specified `$('.my-row-details').hide();` on page load as well. Both of them were contradicting each other.

The solution was to specify `display: none` for my-row-details in css. And then call `.click();` from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the click for that span is working or not by keeping an alert inside the click function, if it is not working then try this

`$('.details').live('click', function(){
    //your logic goes here
});`
or your can try this
`$(".details").bind("click", function(){
    //your logic
});`

---

Hope it works